# Code formatting in specific section

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting, eclipse-pdt

I'm working on a YII project with Eclipse PDT. I would like to know how can I tell Eclipse to  treat a specific section of code as JavaScript, and format it accordingly.
Let's say we are having the following code:

```
      $scriptToBeInjected = "
                    /*how can I format this section in JavaScript code style?*/ 
                   var someJsVariable = function(){};
                    /*end of JavaScript code style*/ 
                            ";

      registerScript('scriptToBeInjected',$scriptToBeInjected,CClientScript::POS_END);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select the section and press "ctrl + shift + F" then it will automatically arrange code.

Comment: I also want it to be seen in coloring format...Not just arrange the code. I know it's much to ask, but i thought maybe there's a solution, like \@formatter:off \@formatter:on ............. \@formatter:on-js \@formatter:off-js

Comment: @klaudyuxxx sorry it is not provided in the eclipse you may just only format the code it will not highlight the code when you format it. :)